# My app got many errors once I imported the gradle to android studio from unity. Is an import problem?

Tags: android, android-studio

I got a long list of errors only when importing my Unity gradle into android studio. I think it may be an issue with the way I imported the files. If that is the issue, what would be the best way to transfer the project from unity to android studio? Any advice is appreciated.

```
2019-01-26 15:33:37.700 1522-1533/? E/vold: Failed to chmod /data/system_ce/0: No such file or directory
2019-01-26 15:33:37.700 1522-1533/? E/vold: Failed to chmod /data/misc_ce/0: No such file or directory
2019-01-26 15:33:37.700 1522-1533/? E/vold: Failed to chmod /data/media/0: No such file or directory
2019-01-26 15:34:13.500 1700-1732/? E/storaged: getService package_native failed
2019-01-26 15:34:13.504 1700-1732/? E/storaged: getDiskStats failed with result NOT_SUPPORTED and size 0
2019-01-26 15:34:18.575 1700-1732/? E/storaged: getService package_native failed
2019-01-26 15:34:42.877 1522-1533/? E/vold: Failed to read field SystemLocale: No such file or directory
2019-01-26 15:34:55.456 1590-1590/? E/android.hardware.wifi@1.0-service: Failed to register radio mode change callback
2019-01-26 15:34:55.538 1590-1590/? E/android.hardware.wifi@1.0-service: Failed to set DFS flag; DFS channels may be unavailable.
2019-01-26 15:34:55.548 1701-1701/? E/wificond: No Offload Service available
2019-01-26 15:35:13.683 2088-2195/? E/ActivityThread: Failed to find provider info for com.android.contacts
2019-01-26 15:35:19.833 1700-1732/? E/storaged: getDiskStats failed with result NOT_SUPPORTED and size 0
2019-01-26 15:35:20.303 1974-2211/? E/ActivityThread: Failed to find provider info for com.android.contacts
2019-01-26 15:35:21.181 1974-2211/? E/ActivityThread: Failed to find provider info for com.android.contacts
2019-01-26 15:35:21.489 1974-2209/? E/ActivityThread: Failed to find provider info for com.android.contacts
2019-01-26 15:35:25.422 2304-2304/? E/ActivityThread: Failed to find provider info for com.google.android.gsf.gservices
2019-01-26 15:35:25.634 2304-2304/? E/ActivityThread: Failed to find provider info for com.google.android.gsf.gservices
2019-01-26 15:35:25.680 2304-2304/? E/ActivityThread: Failed to find provider info for com.google.android.gsf.gservices
2019-01-26 15:35:25.680 2304-2304/? E/ActivityThread: Failed to find provider info for com.google.android.gsf.gservices
2019-01-26 15:35:25.682 2304-2304/? E/ActivityThread: Failed to find provider info for com.google.android.gsf.gservices
2019-01-26 15:35:25.682 2304-2304/? E/ActivityThread: Failed to find provider info for com.google.android.gsf.gservices
2019-01-26 15:36:19.835 1700-1732/? E/storaged: getDiskStats failed with result NOT_SUPPORTED and size 0
2019-01-26 15:36:24.102 2450-2497/? E/ActivityThread: Failed to find provider info for com.google.android.as.allapps.actionsettingprovider
2019-01-26 15:36:24.941 2450-2450/? E/SchedPolicy: set_timerslack_ns write failed: Operation not permitted
2019-01-26 15:36:58.617 2998-2998/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.nested.roloffbenjamin.plz, PID: 2998
    java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: No implementation found for java.lang.String com.nested.roloffbenjamin.plz.MainActivity.stringFromJNI()
```

Answer (score 0):

When building your project to Android in Unity, there is a setting to Export Project. This will generate you a valid Gradle Project that you can open with Android Studio. Here are the official [docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/android-gradle-overview.html).